# No me funciona la etiqueta ":last-child{}" CSS3

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy probando las etiquetas de `CSS3` y la etiqueta `:last-child` me funciona solo en parte de mi código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Pagina de curso html 5" />
  <title>Nuevas reglas CSS3</title>

  <style>
    p:last-child {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Hola</p>
  <p>Adios</p>
  <p>Febrero</p>

  <ol>
    <li>Manzana</li>
    <li>Limon</li>
    <li>
      <p>Pera</p>
      <p>Melon</p>
      <p>Naranja</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p><br>Abril</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Aquí el ultimo hijo `p` de la lista ordenada **si se pone en rojo** pero el hijo `p` del `body` **no**, no se por que. He probado quitando la `ol` y sigue sin funcionar.

Ayuda! Gracias.

Comment: podrias utilizar `last-of-type` pero tambien te seleccionaria naranja uwu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto se debe a que, aunque no lo veas, hay un elemento que se inserta antes del final del `<body>`. En el caso de los snippets the StackOverflow, se inserta un `<script>` con el código JS. Fuera de este ejemplo concreto, puede ser porque alguna herramienta que usas o algún plugin de tu navegador esté insertando algo antes del cierre del `</body>`.

La solución más sencilla sería envolver todo el contenido del `body` dentro de una etiqueta, como por ejemplo `div`:

```css
p:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hola</p>
  <p>Adios</p>
  <p>Febrero</p>

  <ol>
    <li>Manzana</li>
    <li>Limon</li>
    <li>
      <p>Pera</p>
      <p>Melon</p>
      <p>Naranja</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p><br>Abril</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si lo envuelves todo en un div contenedor funciona correctamente.

```css
p:last-child {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Pagina de curso html 5" />
  <title>Nuevas reglas CSS3</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
  <p>Hola</p>
  <p>Adios</p>
  <p>Febrero</p>

  <ol>
    <li>Manzana</li>
    <li>Limon</li>
    <li>
      <p>Pera</p>
      <p>Melon</p>
      <p>Naranja</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p>Abril</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```